# JSON for Questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, json

Could we get JSON for Questions?

```
 0. Question ID                  44965
 1. Question Title               What is a monad?
 2. Author ID                    3394
 3. Last Edited Author ID        1122
 4. DateTime Asked               2008-09-04 23:26:44Z UTC
 5. DateTime Last Edited         2008-09-15 20:14:18Z UTC
 6. First n-chars                Having briefly looked at Haskell recently...
 7. Tags                         functional-programming, monads
 8. Number of Answers            13
 9. Accepted Answer ID           -1 (No Accepted Answer)
10. Last Answer Author ID        47978
11. Last Answer DateTime         2009-06-23 23:24:24Z UTC
```

What am I missing?

Also, if I'm not mistaken, wouldn't this practically serve as JSON for Answers too? They're essentially the same thing in the database, right?

Comment: In what context do you want to use this info? I have a tool which can analyize the questions listings HTML for this kind of information in Java.

Comment: @kd304 Any method of getting this data currently would be inefficient. Requesting it is a good step, but probably won't be considered until an API gets underway.

Comment: @Ian Elliot: It depends, currently I get the active listings with tag filter and 50 entries in about 1.4 seconds (raw HTML). It's slow I admit, but can fire off the analysis in parallel for all 3 sites at once.

Comment: I'm aware I could scrape this. But I would much rather *not* abuse the servers :)

Comment: I didn't mean inefficient with speed, but the fact that you have to pull much more information then you actually need.

Comment: You do realize that many people have pushed hard for an API to no avail? It's sort of a running theme...

Comment: True, I had also similar request once for API enhancements, but status-planned. If you imitate a browser and restrict yourself for a 30 sec/query it shouldn't be abuse.

Comment: Kyle, this isn't an API *(jedi mind-trick hand-wave)*, It's just a variant of the flair code.

Comment: @kd304, 30sec/query will definitely be flagged as possible abuse if you continue long enough. The guideline Jeff gave me was one scrape every 15 minutes.